# How to solve Deadline exceeded error on google cloud functions for firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

We are working in a project with google cloud functions for Firebase. We have the blaze plan but we are facing some execution problems with background functions when it comes to deal with read/write good deal of documents from/to Firebase.

The functions just throw some errors after some time of execution or do not complete the task at all.

I have tried to scale up the RAM assigned to the function (2 GB) and the wait time (540 seconds)

**Index.js:**

```
exports.createRDTCode = functions.runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540,
  memory: '2GB'}).firestore.document("xxxxx/{project}").onUpdate((change, context, callback) => { 
  return createRDTCode.handler(change,context,callback)
})
```

**createRDTCode.js:**

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const firestore = admin.firestore();

exports.handler = async (change, context) => {
  const newValue = change.after.data();
  const previousValue = change.before.data();
  let barsConsecutivo = newValue.barras;

  if (
    newValue.writeCode != previousValue.writeCode &&
    newValue.writeCode == true
  ) {
    const drillingRDTRef = admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("xxxxxxx")
      .doc(context.params.project);

    drillingRDTRef.update({
      writeCode: false
    });
    const project = context.params.project.split("_", 2)[0];
    const company = context.params.project.split("_", 2)[1];

    const projectRef = admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("xxxxxxx")
      .doc(context.params.project);

    const barsRef = admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("xxxxx")
      .doc(context.params.project)
      .collection("xxxxx")
      .where("idRDT", "==", null);


    barsRef.get().then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(rdtDoc => {
        let barCode = (
          company.substr(0, 2) +
          project.substr(0, 2) +
          "BA" +
          barsConsecutivo.toString()
        ).toUpperCase();

        admin
          .firestore()
          .collection("xxxxxx")
          .doc(context.params.project)
          .collection("xxxxx")
          .doc(rdtDoc.id)
          .update({
            idRDT: barCode
          });

        projectRef.update({
          drillingRDT: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(barCode),
          inventory: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(barCode)
        });

        admin
          .firestore()
          .collection("xxxxxxx")
          .doc(context.params.project)
          .collection(rdtDoc.data().typeInventory.toLowerCase())
          .doc(barCode)
          .set({
            typeRDT: rdtDoc.data().tipoRDT,
            codeRDT: barCode,
            statusRDT: rdtDoc.data().statusRDT,
            rigArray: rdtDoc.data().rigArray,
            typeInventory: rdtDoc.data().typeInventory.toLowerCase(),
            numberHoles: rdtDoc.data().numberHoles,
            lengthHole: rdtDoc.data().lengthHole
          });

        barsConsecutivo += 1;
      });

      const drillingRDTRef = admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("xxxxxxx")
        .doc(context.params.project);


      drillingRDTRef.update({
        barras: barsConsecutivo

      });


    });
  }


};
```

The error we are gettings is:

> Error: Deadline exceeded
>   at Http2CallStream.call.on (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:96:45)
>   at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
>   at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
>   at process.nextTick (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:71:22)
>   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
>   at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)

Comment: I have the same issue, have you found a solution?

Comment: I have been checking the firebase functions repo on GitHub and they haven´t been able to fix the error. We have to take in to account that firebase functions stills in version beta, so it will have some errors for now.

In our case the error happenned when we tried to read/write a lot of documents (+100) in the same function excecution so the solution was to write a recursive function that paginates over the collection a get subsets of 50 documents and perform the respective tasks.

If you need some help with the code tell me and I'll share my approach.

Comment: @MaicolLlanoMoncada what is your solution? We have the same problem